# How to interpret the construction "...something of evidence, the evidence being ..."?

Tags: translation

While reading an [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-value?oldformat=true#Basic_concepts) I stumbled upon this:

> **The p-value is used in the context of null hypothesis testing in order to quantify the idea of statistical significance of evidence, the evidence being the observed value of the chosen statistic T.**

I don't quite understand the second part of this sentence. I think it means *"where the evidence is the observed value of the chosen statistic T"*. How exactly should I interpret the words *"the evidence being ..."*? And, by the way, what is the name for the corresponding grammar section?

Comment: What you interpreted is absolutely correct. Don't worry.